# MySQL error 1436: Thread stack overrun, with simple query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am doing a very simple update on a table, which also triggers a really simple trigger, and it gives me the error

```
#1436 - Thread stack overrun:  6136 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.
```

The query I execute:

```
UPDATE field_values SET value = 'asaf' WHERE field_values.id =1
```

The value field is a `text` field. So in theory it could become quiet big. Which is not the case in this situation.

The trigger that's getting executed is:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER field_value_update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON community_fields_values
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      INSERT INTO user_field_log (user_id, field_id, value) VALUES (NEW.user_id, NEW.field_id, NEW.value);
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Why is this error showing? It's not like there is any heavy query involved. Also note that the database is almost empty, just 2 rows in `community_fields_values` and no rows in the `user_field_log`

MySQL version: 5.1.44

Comment: can you post the entire trigger code please

Comment: @f00 I added the entire trigger

Comment: @jan I added the version in the topic

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## 1436 - Thread stack overrun:  6136 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.

The error 1436 corresponds to ER_STACK_OVERRUN_NEED_MORE in the mysql 5.1 code :

```
malff@linux-8edv:include> pwd
/home/malff/BZR_TREE/mysql-5.1/include
malff@linux-8edv:include> grep 1436 mysqld_error.h
#define ER_STACK_OVERRUN_NEED_MORE 1436
```

The code printing the error seen is in sql/sql_parse.cc,
function check_stack_overrun() :

```
bool check_stack_overrun(THD *thd, long margin,
                         uchar *buf __attribute__((unused)))
{
  long stack_used;
  DBUG_ASSERT(thd == current_thd);
  if ((stack_used=used_stack(thd->thread_stack,(char*) &stack_used)) >=
      (long) (my_thread_stack_size - margin))
  {
    char ebuff[MYSQL_ERRMSG_SIZE];
    my_snprintf(ebuff, sizeof(ebuff), ER(ER_STACK_OVERRUN_NEED_MORE),
                stack_used, my_thread_stack_size, margin);
    my_message(ER_STACK_OVERRUN_NEED_MORE, ebuff, MYF(ME_FATALERROR));
```

From the values seen, margin is 128000, and my_thread_stack_size is 131072.

The only call to check_stack_overrun() that tries to reserve 128000 bytes is from:

```
bool
sp_head::execute(THD *thd)
{
  /* Use some extra margin for possible SP recursion and functions */
  if (check_stack_overrun(thd, 8 * STACK_MIN_SIZE, (uchar*)&old_packet))
    DBUG_RETURN(TRUE);
```

The value of STACK_MIN_SIZE is 16000:

```
malff@linux-8edv:sql> pwd
/home/malff/BZR_TREE/mysql-5.1/sql
malff@linux-8edv:sql> grep STACK_MIN_SIZE *.h
mysql_priv.h:#define STACK_MIN_SIZE          16000   // Abort if less stack during eval.
```

So far, everything works as expected for the server:

- the code executes a trigger, which is implemented with
  sp_head::execute.
- the MySQL runtime checks that there is at least 128000 bytes on the stack
- this check fails (rightly so), and the trigger execution ends with an error.

The amount of stack needed by the MySQL trigger execution does not depends on the trigger complexity itself, or the content / structure of the tables involved.

What the *real* question is, I guess, why is the thread_stack only at 128K (131072).

The server variable named 'thread_stack' is implemented in C as 'my_thread_stack_size' in sql/mysqld.cc :

```
  {"thread_stack", OPT_THREAD_STACK,
   "The stack size for each thread.", &my_thread_stack_size,
   &my_thread_stack_size, 0, GET_ULONG, REQUIRED_ARG,DEFAULT_THREAD_STACK,
   1024L*128L, ULONG_MAX, 0, 1024, 0},
```

1024L*128L is the minimum value for this parameter.
The default value is DEFAULT_THREAD_STACK, which is defined in include/my_pthread.h:

```
#ifndef DEFAULT_THREAD_STACK
#if SIZEOF_CHARP > 4
/*
  MySQL can survive with 32K, but some glibc libraries require > 128K stack
  To resolve hostnames. Also recursive stored procedures needs stack.
*/
#define DEFAULT_THREAD_STACK    (256*1024L)
#else
#define DEFAULT_THREAD_STACK    (192*1024)
#endif
#endif
```

So, by default, the stack size should be 192K (32bits) or 256K (64bits architectures).

First, check how the mysqld binary was compiled, to see what is the default value:

```
malff@linux-8edv:sql> pwd
/home/malff/BZR_TREE/mysql-5.1/sql
malff@linux-8edv:sql> ./mysqld --no-defaults --verbose --help | grep thread_stack
...
  --thread_stack=#    The stack size for each thread.
thread_stack                      262144
```

On my system, I got 256K on a 64 bits platform.

If there are different values, maybe someone build the server with different compiling options, such as -DDEFAULT_THREAD_STACK (or just modified the source) ... I would question where the binary is coming from in that case.

Second, check my.cnf for default values provided in the configuration file itself.
A line setting a value to thread_stack explicitly (and with a low value) would definitively cause the error seen.

Last, check the server log file for an error such as this (see sql/mysqld.cc) :

```
sql_print_warning("Asked for %lu thread stack, but got %ld",
                  my_thread_stack_size, (long) stack_size);
```

The server code calls:

- pthread_attr_setstacksize() to set the stack size
- pthread_attr_getstacksize() to verify how much stack a thread really have
  and complains in the log if the pthread library used less.

Long story short, the error is seen because the thread_stack is too small compared to the default values shipped with the server.
This can happen:

- when doing custom builds of the server, with different compiling
  options
- when changing the default value in the my.cnf file
- if something went wrong in the pthread library itself (in theory from
  reading the code, I never have seen it myself).

I hope this answer the question.

Regards,
-- Marc Alff

Update (2014-03-11), to make the "how to fix" more obvious.

What is going on, in all likelihood, is that the default value for thread_stack file was changed in the my.cnf file.

How to fix it is trivial then, find where thread_stack is set in the my.cnf file, and either remove the setting (trusting the server code to provide a decent default value, so this does not happen again next time) or increase the stack size.

Update (2021-04-28), check where the thread_stack comes from:

Use table `performance_schema.variables_info` to find out where a given variable comes from.

```
mysql> select * from variables_info where VARIABLE_NAME = 'thread_stack';
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_SOURCE | VARIABLE_PATH | MIN_VALUE | MAX_VALUE            | SET_TIME | SET_USER | SET_HOST |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| thread_stack  | COMPILED        |               | 131072    | 18446744073709550592 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here the default is the factory value (compiled in the mysqld binary).

Another example:

```
mysql> select * from variables_info where VARIABLE_NAME = 'thread_stack';
+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_SOURCE | VARIABLE_PATH                                                  | MIN_VALUE | MAX_VALUE            | SET_TIME | SET_USER | SET_HOST |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| thread_stack  | EXPLICIT        | /home/malff/CODE/GIT/GIT_TRUNK/build-dbg/mysql-test/var/my.cnf | 131072    | 18446744073709550592 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here the thread_stack is set in the my.cnf file reported.

Refman:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-variables-info-table.html

Comment: This greatly explains the "what´s going on here". However, it obfuscates the "how to fix" part.

Comment: I also got the 131072 byte stack on an EL6 (CentOS6) system (64-bits).  Excellent answer, though my vote goes for the other post that gives a short and concise solution to the problem :-)  POST-EDIT: found that someone actually had hard-coded thread_stack = 128k in the config.  Probably it's been standing there for more than a decade :-)

Comment: @tobixen, thanks for the comments. Personally, I like my answer better (biased of course), especially for the last part : "remove the setting ... so this does not happen again next time". It might (have to wait another decade to find out) be a better solution.

Comment: I'm wondering a bit if the 128k setting came from the RHEL6 mysql package, because I can't find it in our puppet repository.  If so, this may be a "bug" that should be reported to RedHat, but I don't feel motivated to follow up on it now.

Comment: @MarcAlff, Admittedly the actual question in the posting was "Why is this error showing?", which makes your answer the best one - but I think that for the majority of people arriving here through some popular search engine, the other answer is probably what they are searching for :-)

Comment: **CHECK YOUR SQL!!!** For me it was not about resources, it was simply a recursive of function calls (stored-procedures) that made the stack so big. I had to fix the SQL and it solved the problem.

Comment: I wanted to use `ini_set()` to fix this up ...not possible/available.  Ended up refactoring code instead.

Comment: @tobixen unable to find the `thread_stack` setting anywhere in `my.init` and also there is no above mentioned header in include. I am on MySQL 8.0 Windows. How to increase the size of the stack. I want it to be 4 times for handling my queries.

Comment: @mr.loop, table performance_schema.variables_info will show where a system variable value comes from, see updated answer.

Comment: @MarcAlff thanks, I actually progressed from that step but got stuck later. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301980/contradictory-configuration-of-server-and-mysqld-in-mysql

Answer (score 41):

Although not a solution, but a quick fix could be to increase the thread_stack size by incrementing it in your my.cnf:

thread_stack = 256K

As user "foo" pointed out, posting the whole trigger code might be more helpful in order to detect the real problem.

Comment: Perfect for single-use procedures you just need to make a complex modification and forget about.

Comment: Actually, this *is* the solution -- trigger complexity and thread stack size aren't particularly related to each other, and when your thread stack is too small, you make it bigger.  Anything below 256K on a 64-bit system is too small.

Comment: This worked for me, if you are having problems finding the my.cnf file, use 'Show Variables' to get your mysql basdir and will point you in the right direction. File might also be called my.ini. You need to stop and start the task/service so this update takes effect.

Comment: it works for me, thanks. I set it to 10M in my.ini  -  I found the my.ini file checking mysql service properties from services.msc command in Win+R for windows os