# MySQL create trigger doesn't quite work for this query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I created a trigger, at least, I'm trying to. But my query doesn't quite work. What am I missing here?
The query inside the trigger works perfectly on it's own:

```
INSERT INTO user_signup_log (user_id) VALUES (4)
```

This is my trigger query:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER user_signup_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON site_users
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      INSERT INTO user_signup_log (user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id)
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The error I'm getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 4
```

I followed instructions from another question here on stackoverflow how to create a trigger. And I also was able to create a different trigger with a similar query, and that one does work. You can find that one in another [question, which is still unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER user_signup_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON site_users
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO user_signup_log (user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id);
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use this one -

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_signup_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON site_users
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO user_signup_log (user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id);
```