# how to use "mysqld -O thread_stack=#"

Tags: java, mysql

I keep getting this error whether I run my query from the terminal or from within Java. Anyone has some instructions how to resolve this?

```
Thread stack overrun:  5768 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.
Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.com

Comment: I didn't know those existed. I reposted. thanks.

Comment: But no one over there has answered

Answer (score 3):

The my.cnf file for the mysql server most likely contains a line like:

```
thread_stack=128K
```

Either remove this line completely, so that the server uses the default value (which is now higher), or use a bigger value.

See related question :

[MySQL error 1436: Thread stack overrun, with simple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query)

and in particular my answer there.

Comment: I tried this before posting. in fact, I had to create the file. but that didn't work.

Comment: This change solved my problem. I was on windows if that helps anyone

Comment: @Avnish there is no `my.cnf` file in my windows, only a `my.ini` file and that too in hidden folder of ProgramData not in Program Files. and there is no `thread_stack` line in that .ini file and adding this too doesn't work.