# Something wrong in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql

i have two mysql tables - **employee** and **employee_log**

i have written below trigger for it, intention is, what data is inserted in **employee** same data should be inserted in **employee_log**.

```
    delimiter |
    CREATE TRIGGER `emp`  
    AFTER INSERT ON `employee` 
    FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO employee_log (id,userId,firstname,lastname)  
    VALUES (NEW.id,NEW.userId,NEW.firstname,NEW.lastname);  
    END |
```

above trigger is executes well,
   Now i have tried insert record in employee table it is giving me below error, i have no idea what went wrong here, please help ..

```
     Error is -
 #1436 - Thread stack overrun: 5848 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed. Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

Comment: may not be related, but you have not restored delimiter to ";"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting value of `thread_stack` global variable to default value `196608` in `my.cnf` file and then restart the MySQL server also try:

```
thread_stack = 256K
```

I hope you find answer here: [MySQL error 1436: Thread stack overrun, with simple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query)