# Cannot return results from mySQL stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to pull data from a stored procedure using PDO, and I'm having a really rough time nailing this down. I've searched around for the last few days and cannot seem to find a direct solution to my problem.

This is how I created the procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_searchArticles(
   IN tagList VARCHAR(255), 
   IN lastArticle INT(10), 
   OUT  data INT(10))
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE at_results (
id INTEGER(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
article_id INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
common_tags INTEGER NOT NULL)
SELECT at.article_id, art.datetime, Count(at.article_id) AS common_tags
FROM article_tags AS at 
INNER JOIN articles AS art ON at.article_id = art.article_id
WHERE at.tag_id IN (tagList)
GROUP BY at.article_id
ORDER BY common_tags DESC, art.datetime DESC;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE at_article
SELECT id
FROM at_results
WHERE article_id = lastArticle;

SELECT article_id
INTO data
FROM at_results, at_article
WHERE at_results.id > at_article.id;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then I call the SP using PDO:

```
$sql = "CALL sp_searchArticles(:tag_list, :last_article, @data)";
$tag_sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$tag_sth->bindParam(':tag_list', $tag_list);
$tag_sth->bindParam(':last_article', $last_article);
$tag_sth->execute();
$data = $this->db->query("select @data")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But it returns "#1436 - Thread stack overrun:"

I have tried calling the stored procedure without using @data out variables, but I get HY000 errors. I did not originally want this call to be a stored procedure, but PDO doesn't seem to like the face that I have multiple statements in a single execution. Also, I cannot seem to call the procedure correctly using static parameters through phpmyadmin. The sql statements work perfectly outside of the procedure, however.

I'm not the most proficient with PDO and mySQL, but I've read a whole lot about bugs within phpmyadmin, PDO, and PHP that pertain to stored procedures. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be utilizing more memory than MySQL is configured to allow you to use.

See:

[MySQL error 1436: Thread stack overrun, with simple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query)

Try changing your my.cnf file, if you have access to it.

Comment: That did the trick... I feel kinda dumb for searching for this long and it took you all of 2 minutes. I even searched around for that error code and I did not stumble across anything that referenced my.cnf. Do you know if there are any negative effects for increasing this number? Thanks!