# Storing longer texts in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, compression, storage

In one of my tables I have a field which can contain longer texts. Everytime someone inserts something into that table a simple trigger is called. My problem is that this gives me an error: #1436 - Thread stack overrun: [...]

I thought that this could be solved by some sort of compression of the text.

What kind of compression should I use for this? I need to be able to "uncompress" it. And note that this isn't to improve security but just to minimize the amount of data.

Comment: You probably mean compression. Encryption typically does not reduce the amount of data, and sometimes even increases it. Additionally, you might want to look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query)

Comment: @TheVedge Yup, edited the text

Comment: Did you take a look at that other post? It seems the problem might be related to configuration/compilation, rather than the size of the row itself

Comment: It's worth nothing that all major DBMS implement large text data types in such a way they column contents are not loaded into memory at once. I'm pretty sure that error #1436 is not caused by using a feature that's actually supported.

Comment: I tried changing the .cnf file but I can't unlock the file (Mac OSX).

Comment: MySQL does not lock the configuration file, you will need to run your editor with elevated privileges (I think OSX has sudo from the command line?)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TheVedge links to a post that might solve your MySQL configuration problem. However, if you would still like to save space by compressing text data inside blob columns (desirable if you have an inordinate amount of data and/or low data limits on a web hosting plan), MySQL includes [built-in compression/decompression functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html). Look at COMPRESS() and UNCOMPRESS(). These are based on standard zlib.