# MySQL trigger error: update another cell on the same row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've got a mysql table 'market' with columns

1. open_time (datetime),
2. session_num (int),
3. duration (int),
4. end_time (datetime).

I want to make a trigger to automatically calculate and update the value for close_time if someone updates any of [open_time, session_num, duration].

I want `end_time = open_time + session_num * duration;`

I made a trigger like below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `market`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET new.end_time = new.open_time + new.duration * new.session_num;
END
```

However, when I updates open_time, this error comes:

```
#1436 - Thread stack overrun:  13080 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't look now, but the error message is telling you how to fix the problem.

```
Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

The problem is that your thread stack is set to the absolute bare minimum supported value, which isn't big enough, and needs to be bigger.

Set `thread_stack = 256K` in your my.cnf file, restart the server, and you're done.  Your current value seems to be *below* the documented defaults in any version of the 5.x series, so I'm going to suggest that you actually already have a `thread_stack` entry in your configuration that you need to edit, rather than adding a new one.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_stack

I have not personally encountered a situation where 256K is not a sufficient thread stack size, or 192K only if you never, ever, ever have recursive stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

What is the interval - minutes?

Try

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER u_market_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON `market`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 SET new.end_time=new.open_time + interval (new.duration*new.session_num) minute;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Check if you have other triggers that interfer with this one.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query