# Stored procedure for MySQL to convert bigint to UUID

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, uuid

Im trying to convert a legacy bigint field into a sequence of uuids:

```
DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION uuid_from_bigint(b bigint) RETURNS CHAR(36) BEGIN
 DECLARE hex CHAR(32);
 SET hex = lpad(hex(b), 32, '0');
 RETURN CONCAT(LEFT(hex, 8), '-', MID(hex, 9,4), '-', MID(hex, 13,4), '-', MID(hex, 17,4), '-', RIGHT(hex, 12));
END
| 
DELIMITER ;
```

Can someone help me understand why this would cause the following problem?

```
mysql> select uuid_from_bigint(9);
ERROR 1436 (HY000): Thread stack overrun:  12816 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

Comment: Note, I eventually plan to expand this to take two bigint's for the lower and upper part — But I am unable to get past this first hurdle.

Comment: try to change your function to `CREATE FUNCTION uuid_from_bigint(b bigint) RETURNS CHAR(36) BEGIN
 DECLARE hex CHAR(32);
 DECLARE tmp CHAR(36);
 SET hex = lpad(hex(b), 32, '0');
  
  set tmp = CONCAT(LEFT(hex, 8), '-');
  set tmp = CONCAT(tmp, MID(hex, 9,4));
  set tmp = CONCAT(tmp, '-');
  set tmp = CONCAT(tmp, MID(hex, 13,4));
  set tmp = CONCAT(tmp, '-');
  set tmp = CONCAT(tmp, MID(hex, 17,4));
  set tmp = CONCAT(tmp, '-');
  set tmp = CONCAT(tmp, RIGHT(hex, 12));
  return tmp;
END` and test whether problem still here

Comment: This is of no help, but your function worked on my server.  You should read this (it made my head spin :) ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no problem with this procedure, the problem is with the thread stack configuration.

You can increase the thread_stack size by incrementing it in your `my.cnf`:

```
thread_stack = 256K
```