# Why is a one-line MySQL stored function overflowing the stack?

Tags: mysql

I'm just learning the stored-function and -procedure syntax for MySQL.  I hard-coded a function that just returns the number 12, and it overflows the stack.  Anybody know what's up here?  This is MySQL 5.5.30.

```
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `newItemID`()
    -> RETURNS BIGINT
    -> SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    -> BEGIN
    ->   RETURN 12;
    -> END;
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> SELECT newItemID();
ERROR 1436 (HY000): Thread stack overrun:  12288 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

Comment: Hm, works here @ 5.5.34, with the same default thread stack  What happens if you add `DETERMINISTIC` & drop the `BEGIN` & `END`? And is this vanilla MySQL?

Comment: `Thread stack overrun:  12288 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack`  Hmm, it looks like you've only used about 1/10th your stack size.  No idea what's going on but that's a weird one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error 1436: Thread stack overrun, with simple query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query)

Comment: Aha, [it is a known bug running with 128k thread stack](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45445), but it _should_ have been fixed in 5.5.9. I'd say this is either regression or you did not install MySQL from the offical packages, but a package maintained by someone other party?

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I'm not in control of the server; it's a typical LAMP hosting service.  I'll take it up with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like @wrikken pointed out this is a known bug when  you're running a 128k thread stack, however it was fixed in newer versions of mysql and it was supposed to be fixed, so maybe you're running an older version or a non-official package.

It is reccommended to use a stack that has at least 192k on it, so you could go to your my-small.cnf and make `my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf:thread_stack = 192k 
my-small.cnf:thread_stack = 128K`.

All of these remedies are available in the [mysql bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45445), but please test this offline before modifying your server. Make sure the offline localhost has the same settings and configurations just like your live server, that is if you're using a live server. Basically make an exact duplicate of your server and test it offline and if the fix works and doesn't cause any issues, put it online.

Comment: Thanks!  This is a LAMP hosting account, so I'll have to get the provider to fix this.  Sigh.

Comment: The host eventually patched the installation, resolving this problem.  Thanks again everybody.