# MySQL stored function does not return same results when ran - retrieving parent id's

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I am attempting to retrieve a list of categories based on their parent Id from an SQL table.  The query works correctly when ran as a normal query, but when the same code is copied into a stored function returns duplicate entries.

I was unable to get query to return multiple categories so have tried a stored function that I understood show be able to do this.

I have excluded the whole query but would like to be able to call from the SELECT statement, i.e.

```
SELECT field1, field2, get_parent_categories(562) FROM...
```

The following works as required as it returns "65 > 562 > 1030"
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fc8acc/3

Next is the stored function that doesn't work as it returns " 562 > 562 > 562 ... " repeated 256 times.  However, I am getting an "Thread stack overrun" error in sqlfiddle when attempting to run the same that I have been testing locally.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09a64b/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`categories_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8//

INSERT INTO `categories` (`categories_id`, `parent_id`) VALUES (1030, 0),(562,65),(65,1030)//

CREATE FUNCTION get_parent_categories(_lookup_category_id INT) RETURNS LONGTEXT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE _id INT;
    DECLARE _categories LONGTEXT DEFAULT "no categories";

    #CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mycats
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.categories_id SEPARATOR " > ") INTO _categories

    FROM (
        SELECT
            @r AS _id,
            (SELECT @r := parent_id FROM categories WHERE categories_id = _id) AS parent_id
        FROM
            (SELECT @r := _lookup_category_id) vars, categories
        WHERE @r <> 0) T1
    JOIN categories c ON T1._id = c.categories_id;

    RETURN _categories;

END//
```

Comment: Do you get this error on a real server? You can't adjust the thread stack limit on sqlfiddle, you should be able to do it on your server. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query

Comment: No, I don't get any error on my local server, it just returns  562 > 562 > 562 ... " repeated 256 times rather than "65 > 562 > 1030".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias of the column (`_id`) and the local variable (`_id`) may be the cause.

Try:

```sql
...
CREATE FUNCTION get_parent_categories(_lookup_category_id INT) RETURNS LONGTEXT
...
  -- DECLARE _id INT;
...
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=877ddda347736cdce34f95a69294e7f3).